# if a fuction that returns promise is called and returned in next line will execution of the called function stop?

Tags: node.js, async-await, promise

if we dont use async await then will the execution of callToFunction() stops when return is called?
Or is it that we need to use async await to execute the function properly?
which is the suggested way?

````
{
    callToFunction(); //This function returns a promise
    return;
} ```
````

Comment: No, it will not stop. If the whole thing is implemented as a script (and not as a module which you need to 'require' or 'import' elsewhere), then you can place `callToFunction();` as the very last line in that script. If you do so, then the execution of that function is guaranteed to complete before the NodeJS process (in which your script is executed) completes.

Comment: Alternatively, you can `return callToFunction();`, and handle the returned `Promise` object elsewhere in your code.